# python 3 argparse call a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, parsing, command-line-interface, argparse

I wanted to create a commandline-like / shell-like interface in python3.

Argparse seems to do the job of parsing and displaying the help/error messages. According to the [python3 documentation of argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html), there is a **func=** argument that can be used to get your **function called by argparse**.

```
# sub-command functions
def foo(args):
   print(args.x * args.y)
def bar(args):
    print('((%s))' % args.z)
# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
# create the parser for the "foo" command
parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
parser_foo.add_argument('-x', type=int, default=1)
parser_foo.add_argument('y', type=float)
parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)
# create the parser for the "bar" command
parser_bar = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
parser_bar.add_argument('z')
parser_bar.set_defaults(func=bar)
```

But as far as I can tell `help_parser.set_defaults(func=foo)` does not call my funciton. It would be appreciated if you could help me.

You can reproduce the issue by running the program with python3, typing `help` and then press [Enter]. It does not print `hello` as expected.
Thanks!

```
def foo():
    print('hello')


class Console:
    def __init__(self):
        """Console like interface for navigating and interacting with the external file system."""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Console like interface for navigating and interacting with the external file system.',
            add_help=False)
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
        subparsers.required = True

        help_parser = subparsers.add_parser('help')
        help_parser.add_argument('-x', type=int, default=1)
        help_parser.set_defaults(func=foo)

        setting_parser = subparsers.add_parser('settings')
        setting_subparsers = setting_parser.add_subparsers(dest='settings_command')
        setting_subparsers.required = True

        setting_save_parser = setting_subparsers.add_parser('save', help='Save the current settings in a .json file.')
        setting_save_parser.add_argument('file', type=str, nargs='?', default='settings.json')

        setting_load_parser = setting_subparsers.add_parser('load', description='Load the last settings from a .json file.')
        setting_load_parser.add_argument('file', type=str, nargs='?', help='settings.json')

        setting_set_parser = setting_subparsers.add_parser('set')
        setting_set_parser.add_argument('--host', type=str, required=True)
        setting_set_parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', type=str, required=True)
        setting_set_parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', type=str, required=True)
        setting_set_parser.add_argument('-x', '--proxy', type=str, required=False)

        while True:
            try:
                print('', flush=True, sep='')
                data = input('>>>').split(' ')
                print('your command:', data)
                parser.parse_args(data)
            except SystemExit:
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Spawn an commandline like interface."""
    c = Console()
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually `argparse` won't call the method automatically - you have to do it yourself. All it does it adds the method to the `func` attribute of the args. So, what you could do is to check if `func` attribute exists and then invoke it as following:

```
args = parser.parse_args(data)
if hasattr(args, 'func'):
    args.func()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to make it work:
The `args.func()` will call the function that got selected by argparse.

```
print('', flush=True, sep='')
data = input('>>>').split(' ')
print('your command:', data)
args = parser.parse_args(data)
print(args)
args.func()
```

Commandline log:

```
>>>help
your command: ['help']
Namespace(command='help', func=<function foo at 0x0000023C3737F7B8>, x=1)
hello
```