# Subparser function calls

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

How do I call the following functions below based on user input?

For example, if they type:

> python test.py cmd1 -n hostname

- it will call def cmd1 and pass the -n parameter (hostname) to function

  ```
  import argparse

  def cmd1(node):
    print('cmd1')

  def cmd1_option1():
    print('cmd2')

  def cmd1_option1(template):
    print('cmd3')


  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='Functions')
  command_1 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd1', help='...')
  command_1.add_argument('-n', "--node", type=str, help='...')

  command_2 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd2', help='...')

  command_3 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd3', help='...')
  command_3.add_argument('-t', "--template", type=int, help='...')

  args = parser.parse_args()
  ```

Comment: See recent SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/51122046/901925

Comment: Or add a `dest='cmd'` to the `add_subparsers` call, and check `args.cmd` for appropriate string value.